# On the iPhone - How do you POST GPS Co-Ordinates to a Server while the application is in the background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, multitasking

I'm interested in sending GPS coordinates to server, via a http call..." The answer's so far have been you can receive gps co-ordinates in the background, but I never seem to get the answer to the actual question:

Question:
Does the iPhone allow for GPS coordinates to be SENT to an external server, using an HTTP post, if the application that is performing this HTTP POST is running in the background? And if so can someone please explain, what we have to do. 
We are aware we can GET the co-ordinates, but now we want to POST that data to a server, without having to consistently ask the user for permission.